# How do i report an Email crime in Germany?

Tags: internet, germany, regulations

A couple of German companies are making money off my name. Since they do not care about my requests to remove my name from their sites and Google refuses to remove them from the Google search I would like to get in touch with the German internet regulator.

Does anyone know what legal recourse I have in Germany? For instance, what is the name for the German internet regulator (national level)? What other legal authorities should I complain to? Or should I sue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about law.

Comment: @feetwet: I expanded the question so that it now encompasses law, and wonder if it can be re-opened in its current form.

Comment: @TomAu - I just reopened, but I personally still can't make sense of it.  I don't understand the tort or crime at stake ("Email crime?").  I'm also having a hard time imagining what a "German internet regulator" would be in this context.  As presently written I'd vote to close as "unclear what you're asking," but at this point I'll defer to others.

Comment: @feetwet: I did my best to give the OP a "second chance." The rest is up to him. As for "internet regulator," probably the German equivalent of the FCC.

Comment: I think BNetzA, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Network_Agency

Comment: Could you expand on what "making money off my name" means?  Are they putting up reviews in your name that you didn't submit?  Sending your access logs to advertisers?

Comment: I have voted to close this as "unclear what you're asking" because it is unclear to me what is actually happening. You mention that a site is "making money off [your] name" but it's not clear what that means. Also, I am completely unable to associate the body of the question with the title, which mentions some kind of nebulous "Email crime" while the body does not mention email at all.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Polizei.de.
(I was referred to this Website by Europol)